# Drupal: The easiest way to create HTML page without usage of drupal

Tags: html, drupal-6

How can I make Drupal "print" the `.html` file which is stored inside Drupal directory (e.g. in drupal root directory, or in `sites/all/files/`)?

I want to get that `.html` file by simple path like `http://www.mydomain.com/thatfile.html`, without theming, etc.

**P.S.** to explain the motivation: I want users to be able to print the location map from the site (pressing "Print map" link). I could do it not redirecting the user to new tab (I want them to be redirected to new tab `:)`). But what if user will accidentally press "Cancel"? (User can become confused)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get it as is? Like regular html page?

Comment: You can add rule to .htaccess for that file, to work around drupal completely.

Comment: @Ivan Ivanić: Should I use `<Files myfile.html>` in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Something like this: RewriteRule ^/thatfile\.html$ - [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Drupal is hosted on http://example.com/, and there is a file named results.html, visiting http://example.com/results.html you will get the content of that HTML file.
One of the rewrite rules included in the .htaccess file Drupal comes with says to the web server to serve a file that exists.

Comment: Oh, really! There is a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `:)` Didn't notice that before.